# Iniciar servidor php com livereload com gulp

Tags: php, gulp, gulpjs

Iniciei meus estudos com gulp e adorei o livereload, porém consegui somente com arquivos estáticos como nesse [link](http://blog.da2k.com.br/2015/03/01/gulp-connect-e-livereload/). O meu objetivo é iniciar o gulp, porém no servidor php embutido (localhost -s Localhost:8000) ou no servidor com Xampp ou Lampp, ao invés do servidor node. Vi algumas pessoas comentando uma [solução](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27990781/gulp-webapp-running-browsersync-and-php) com [browsersync](http://www.browsersync.io/) e outra com [gulp-connect-php](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-connect-php) mas não consegui implementar ambas.
Caso conheçam alguma solução e que não seja um plugin para o navegador fico agradecido.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depois de alguns dias consegui resolver o meu problema usando o gulp-connect-php e browser-sync no gulp. Na documentação oficial mostra exatamente [um exemplo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-connect-php#examples) como é feito. Vejam como ficou o meu arquivo gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var reload      = browserSync.reload;
var connectPHP  = require('gulp-connect-php');

var paths = {
      php:['*.php'],
      css:['*.css']
    };

gulp.task('php', function(){
    gulp.src(paths.php)
    .pipe(reload({stream:true}));
});

gulp.task('watcher',function(){
    gulp.watch(paths.css).on('change', function () {
      browserSync.reload();
    });
    gulp.watch(paths.php).on('change', function () {
      browserSync.reload();
    });
});

gulp.task('php', function() {
  connectPHP.server({}, function (){
    browserSync({
      proxy: 'localhost:8000'
    });
  });
});

gulp.task('default', ['php', 'watcher']);
```

Pra quem tiver problema na implantação criei um [repositório](https://github.com/adrianoavelino/livereload-gulp-php) no Github como exemplo para quem tiver dificuldade.